# CheerioJS and some issue with scraping

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I scraped html with cheerio and I want to grab class="title" from this... How can I do that? I tried to do that on many ways and It isnt working.. after console.log it returns null.

```
<div class="beatmap" id="914524" style="width:420px;">
    <div class="bmlistt" style="background: 
        url(&quot;//b.ppy.sh/thumb/914524.jpg&quot;)">
        <i class="icon-play"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="bmlist-options" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; width: 24px;">
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
        <a href="/forum/t/858871"><i class="icon-comments"></i></a>
        <a class="require-login beatmap_download_link" href="/d/914524"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="maintext" stop="1">
        <span class="artist">ZUN</span>
        <a href="/s/914524" class="title">Haru no Minato ni</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is scraped code . Tell me how to scrape class="title"  to console and convert to text.

Comment: where is your failing code please?

Answer (score 0):

```
const $ = cheerio.load(content);
const text = $('.title').text();
console.log(text);
```